# Boostrap Datetimepicker with Html.hiddenfor not binding values in controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetimepicker

I am working in an mvc problem and I found my self stuck in a problem trying to bind datetimepicker data to my controller action. I have a view that add a partial to  collection of partial views when the user do some action.

My Models looks like

```
public class CreateOCVM
{

    private string errors { get; set; }

    public operaciones_confidenciales oc { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Restringidas")]
    public ICollection<PersonaMin> restringidas { get; set; }


public class PersonaMin
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string motivo { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime fecha_acceso;
```

In my view I have

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateOC", "OC", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form" }))

<table id="personasRestringidas" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>id</th>
                                        <th>Motivo</th>
                                        <th>Fecha de acceso</th>
                                        <th>Eliminar</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody id="person">
                                    @foreach (PersonaMin item in Model.restringidas)
                                    {

                                            @Html.Partial("~/Views/OC/AddOCRestriccion.cshtml", item)
                                    }
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

When user do some ation I add a new item to the ICOllection restringidas. By making an ajax call to a controller method as follows:

```
function addRestriccion(idPersona) {
if (jQuery.inArray(idPersona, dataset) != 0) {
    $.get('/OC/AddOCRestriccion', { id: idPersona}, function (template) {
        dataset.push(idPersona);
        $("#person").append(template);
        $('#datetimepicker' + idPersona).datetimepicker();
        $('#datetimepicker' + idPersona).datetimepicker({ format: "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm" });
        $("#datetimepicker" + idPersona).on("change.dp", function (e) {
            $('#fechaAcceso' + idPersona).val($("#datetimepicker" + idPersona).datepicker('getFormattedDate'))
        });
    });
}
```

This  call a controller method an returns a partial view that will be added to the main view.

```
        [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AddOCRestriccion(Int32 id)
    {
        PersonaMin item = new PersonaMin();
        item.Id = id;
        persona p = PersonaCollection.getPersonasById(id);
        return PartialView("AddOCRestriccion", item);
    }
```

Edit:
This controller returns the partial view to add in the main one.

```
<tr>
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("restringidas"))
{ 
    <td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Id, new { @placeholder = "id", @id = "ID" })
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.motivo, new { @placeholder = "motivo", @id = "motivo", @class = "form-control" })
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class='input-group date' id="@("datetimepicker" + Model.Id)">
            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.fecha_acceso, new { @id = "fechaAcceso" + Model.Id })
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="deleteAnother($(this).parent().parent())">
                <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
            </button>
        </span>
    </td>

}
```

When I submit the form it is handled by the controller action

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateOC(CreateOCVM ocvm)
    { ... do something ....
```

The problem is that when i check the values on my model all the values are ok but not the one for the datetime (fecha_acceso)

In my view the hidden field for my datetime property has value on it.

[image]

But the value change when i check it on the controller method.

[image]

I tried with diferent aproaches but i always get wrong data on my controller method. Does somebody knows what is happening? Or has somebody a different aproach that can help me to do the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default controller doesn't allow date format as dd-mm-yyyy.
Add below lines in your web.config file to do it

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <globalization culture="en-GB" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I tried this and didn't work, I also tried to format the datetime before passing it to the controller and had the same behavoir.

Comment: Do you need me to do it again and send screenshot?

Comment: Html.LavelFor? that only give me the tag name. Should i put html.value or html.displayfor?

Comment: If i put Html.Value or display for the value is always 01/01/0001 0:00:00

Comment: The value of fecha_acceso is a new value I dont get it from " p = PersonaCollection.getPersonasById(id)" i modify the value on the onchange method of the datepicker 
$("#datetimepicker" + idPersona).on("change.dp", function (e) {
            $('#fechaAcceso' + idPersona).val($("#datetimepicker" + idPersona).datepicker('getFormattedDate'))
        });
the metghod you mention is a method that i forgot to delete from the post cause is not relevant information for the problem

Comment: Nope, i don't understand it the method you mention is not related with the problem

Comment: Try to figure out my friend. Don't wait for us. don't loose the hope. Investigate the code. Let us know what you found. So that we can help you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my Html.BeginCollectionItem helper has problems with DateTime so y change de type of my viewmodel from datetime to string. I know it is a workaround and not the correct solution but the lack of time force me to do it.